# How to make my code be able to create multiple instance

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jmeter, instance

I'm making changes to JMeter Aggregate Report module. I created a new class `StatVisualizerAddOn` which contains the components to add on to the `JPanel` in `StatVisualizer` class, however, only one instance of it can be created currently. If multiple instance is created, data is not accurate.

This is the main part of `StatVisualizerAddOn` class which I wrote

```
public class StatVisualizerAddOn {

    public static JTextField percentLine = null;

    private static String DEFAULT_PERCENT = "90.0";

    private static float percentage;

    private static JFrame errorWindow;

    private static JButton enterPercent;

    public JPanel initCustomization()
    {
        percentage = new Float(DEFAULT_PERCENT)/100;
        //new panel to contain all the elements
        JPanel percentLinePanel = new JPanel();
        //create text field for user input     
        percentLine = new JTextField(5);
        percentLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                percentLine.setText(percentLine.getText());
            }
        });
        percentLine.setEditable(true);
        percentLine.setText(DEFAULT_PERCENT);
        percentLine.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
        //create label beside text field
        JLabel percentLineLabel = new JLabel();
        percentLineLabel.setText("Enter percent line to display (1-100)%:");
        //create the confirmation button
        enterPercent = new JButton();
        enterPercent.setText("Confirm");
        enterPercent.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(checkPercent(percentLine.getText())) //check for valid input
                {  
                    setPercent(percentLine.getText());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorWindow,
                        (percentLine.getText()+"% Line has been set."),"Confirmation",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        enterPercent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,25));

        percentLinePanel.add(percentLineLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        percentLinePanel.add(percentLine, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        percentLinePanel.add(enterPercent, BorderLayout.EAST);

        return percentLinePanel;
    }
```

Of cos, there are methods to get and set the `percentline` `textfield` which i did not copy here.

In my `StatVisualizer` class, I simply added this:

```
public StatVisualizer() {

    super();

    model = new ObjectTableModel(COLUMNS,
            SamplingStatCalculator.class,
            new Functor[] {
                new Functor("getLabel"),   //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getCount"),  //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getMeanAsNumber"),   //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getMedian"),  //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getPercentPoint",  //$NON-NLS-1$
                        new Object[] { StatVisualizerAddOn.getPercent() }),         //90% line
                new Functor("getMin"),  //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getMax"),   //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getErrorPercentage"),   //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getRate"),  //$NON-NLS-1$
                new Functor("getKBPerSecond")   //$NON-NLS-1$
            },
            new Functor[] { null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
            new Class[] { String.class, Long.class, Long.class, Long.class, Long.class,
                          Long.class, Long.class, String.class, String.class, String.class });
    clearData();
    init();
}
```

In the object model, I make it call `StatVisualizerAddOn.getPercent()` to get the input value and in `init()`, I added the following lines:

```
    StatVisualizerAddOn addon = new StatVisualizerAddOn();
    JPanel percentile = addon.initCustomization();
    mainPanel.add(percentile);
```

problem:

(e.g. 1 `StatVisualizer` is created in my program, I input 90% in the `percentline`, it will calculate the 90th percentile.

If 2 `StatVisualizer` is create in my program, 1 input 90% the other input 80% in `percentline`, only 80% will be computed for both `StatVisualizer`)

Need some help on how can I change the code such that multiple `Statvisualizer` can be created without data discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` is not your friend here...

```
public static JTextField percentLine = null;
private static String DEFAULT_PERCENT = "90.0";
private static float percentage;
private static JFrame errorWindow;
private static JButton enterPercent;
```

This means that only a single instance of each of the fields will be shared across all instances of your `StatVisualizerAddOn` object.  Remove the `static` reference, for example

```
public JTextField percentLine = null;
private String DEFAULT_PERCENT = "90.0";
private float percentage;
private JFrame errorWindow;
private JButton enterPercent;
```

Comment: how can i make changes to the variables such that they are unique? even if i remove the static reference, 2 instance of StatVisualizer  still shows the same. do i need additional methods to get/set ?

Comment: The values will be unique for each new instance of `StatVisualizerAddOn` if you remove all the `static` references

Comment: but when in another class StatCalculator, wants to access percentline value, how should i getpercent()? because when i use StatVisualizer.getPercent() which in turn calls addon.getPercent(), it shows an error and wants me to change the method to static

Comment: Without a runnable example, it's difficult to know what to suggest. Either `StatVisualizer` needs to maintain multiple instances of `StatVisualizerAddOn` or you need multiple instances of `StatVisualizer`...

Comment: to be accurate, i need to be able to maintain multiple instance of StatVisualizer which contains StatVisualizerAddOn, thus both needs to support multiple instance

Comment: `StatVisualizerAddOn.getPercent()` should be using a instance of `StatVisualizerAddOn`...`new StatVisualizerAddOn().getPercent()`